# Uninstall-Package inside containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, powershell, containers

I'm trying to uninstall AWS cli using Uninstall-Package after initializing containers, but it always hangs while it's uninstalling, has anybody tried to uninstall software inside containers?

```
Get-Package -Name "AWS SAM Command Line Interface" | Uninstall-Package
```

[image]

Comment: maybe provide a `-Verbose` or `-Debug` switch to it for more info? Perhaps a `-Force` too?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I got some more logging now